# hive collect_set crashes query

Tags: hadoop, collections, hive

I've got the following table:

```
hive> describe tv_counter_stats;
OK
day     string  
event   string  
query_id      string  
userid    string  
headers       string
```

And I want to perform the following query:

```
hive -e 'SELECT 
    day,
    event,
    query_id,
    COUNT(1) AS count,
    COLLECT_SET(userid)
FROM
    tv_counter_stats
GROUP BY 
    day, 
    event, 
    query_id;' > counter_stats_data.csv
```

However, this query fails. But the following query works fine:

```
hive -e 'SELECT 
    day,
    event,
    query_id,
    COUNT(1) AS count
FROM
    tv_counter_stats
GROUP BY 
    day, 
    event, 
    query_id;' > counter_stats_data.csv
```

where I remove the collect_set command. So my question: Has anybody an idea why collect_set might fail in this case?

UPDATE: Error message added:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 3  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 10.49 sec   HDFS Read: 109136387 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 10 seconds 490 msec

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)

Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)

Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

---

UPDATE 2:
I altered the query such that it look now like this:

```
hive -e '
SET mapred.child.java.opts="-server -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC";
SELECT 
    day,
    event,
    query_id,
    COUNT(1) AS count,
    COLLECT_SET(userid)
FROM
    tv_counter_stats
GROUP BY 
    day, 
    event, 
    query_id;' > counter_stats_data.csv
```

However, then I get the following error:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 3  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: Can you add the failure message?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the memory problem, since `collect_set` aggregates data in the memory.

Try increasing heap size and enabling concurrent GC (via setting Hadoop `mapred.child.java.opts` to e.g `-Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) has more information about "GC overhead limit" error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and came across this question, so I thought I'd share the solution I found.

The underlying problem is most likely that Hive is trying to do the aggregation on the mapper side, and the heuristics it uses to manage the in-memory hashmaps for that approach are thrown off by data that is "wide but shallow" -- i.e. in your case, if there are very few user_id values per day/event/query_id group.

I found an [article](http://dev.bizo.com/2013/02/map-side-aggregations-in-apache-hive.html) that explains various ways to address this issue, but most of them are just optimizations to the full-out nuclear option:  disable mapper-side aggregations entirely.

Using `set hive.map.aggr = false;` should do the trick.